# Laravel Migration - Foreign Key SQL Error

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration

I have a hazard_categories table, Which contains a **hazard_category_id**

and in my hazard_videos table I'd like to reference it.

My hazard categories migration is as follows :

```
Schema::create('hazard_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('hazard_category_id');
            $table->string('hazard_category_name');
            $table->string('hazard_category_thumb');
            $table->integer('hazard_category_total');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

I've written my migration as follows :

```
    Schema::table('hazard_videos', function (Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->integer('video_category')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('video_category')->references('hazard_category_id')->on('hazard_categories');
    });
```

But when I run this, I get the MySQL Error :

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`icourse`.`#sql-da4_40df`, CONSTRAINT `hazard_videos_video_category_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`video_category`) REFERENCES `hazard_categorie
  s` (`hazard_category_id`)) (SQL: alter table `hazard_videos` add constraint `hazard_videos_video_category_foreign` foreign key (`video_category`) references `hazard_categories` (`hazard_category_id`))
```

Why would I get this? I've mirrored the Laravel docs, But hit an MySQL Error.

Is there a better way to write my referential integrity constraint?

Comment: check the order of your migration

Comment: Please add the migration of `hazard_categories`.

Comment: Do you use the InnoDB engine in both tables?

Comment: Sure, will modify question...

Comment: Is there already data in `hazard_videos`?

Comment: Yeah, there's data in hazard_videos

Answer (score 1):

If there is already data in your table, the values of `video_category` have to be valid foreign keys:

```php
Schema::table('hazard_videos', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('video_category')->unsigned();
});

HazardVideo::query()->update(['video_category' => 1]);

Schema::table('hazard_videos', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('video_category')->references('hazard_category_id')
      ->on('hazard_categories');
});
```

Or you make the column `nullable`.

Comment: Great, Thank you @Jonas